# Elementor jquery script hiding problem on second click

Tags: jquery, wordpress, toggle, show-hide, elementor

I started a few days ago with jQuery and I have a problem with a test.

I have two buttons to show/hide two sections separately and It's working fine. However, when I click the second time on a button that is already active it hides the section again. Is there any way I can fix this?

I'm trying to use it for a landing page with Elementor in Wordpress. This is the code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
jQuery(function($){
$('.botaocompleto').each(function(i){
$(this).click(function(){ $('.planocompleto').eq(i).toggle();
$('.planobasico').eq(i).hide();
}); });
}); });
</script>
<style>
.botaocompleto{
cursor: pointer;
}
.planocompleto{
display: block;
}
</style>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
jQuery(function($){
$('.botaobasico').each(function(i){
$(this).click(function(){ $('.planobasico').eq(i).toggle();
$('.planocompleto').eq(i).hide();
}); });
}); });
</script>
<style>
.botaobasico{
cursor: pointer;
}
.planobasico{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

[hiding problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTS2G.jpg)

I don't know what to do, I will be grateful if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution: change the display from block to flex adding `.css('display', 'flex')` after toggle.